# Avoid merging two objects from different geometry nodes

Tags: objects, geometry-nodes

I'm doing my first tutorial to learn about blender (the donut) and while adding the sprinkles I wanted to add two types of sprinkles. I added then star shaped sprinkles and everything was good until I saw that some stars are "merging" with the cylindric sprinkles. I tried configuring both objects in one geometry node but I couldn't make appear the two shapes, just stars or cylindric sprinkles. How can I fix the problem?[image: A picture showing how the star is inside the cylindric sprinkle]

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Comment: You can put both sprinkle types (Star and Cylinder) into a collection and bring this into _Geometry Nodes_. On the _Collection Info_ node, enable _Relative_ and also _Separate Children_ and _Reset Children_. In the _Instance on Points_ node enable _Pick Instance_. No need for two different _GN_ nodetrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon said, puting both types of sprinkles will solve the problem, so that:

Remove one GN modifier, put sprinkles in the new collection:

[image]

Drag this collection into geometry nodes and connect it instead of one object:

[image]

To make it work, all of 3 checkboxes marked by arrows should be clicked.

Also, to align star, I applied its transform (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> →rotation) and rotate it in Edit mode to make it perfectly aligned with the surface of the donut.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use collections for your instances, you can just join the geometry of the objects as instances:

[image: Geometry nodes]

Result:

[image: two instances on points]